# Caching not working in Internet Explorer 11 (Windows 7)

Tags: caching, internet-explorer-11

I have a Windows 7 machine with IE11. For some reason the caching feature does not seem to be working. e.g. when I refresh pages I noticed that the js, css and other files are not being cached. In Internet Options - General - Settings, the 'Check for newer versions of stored pages' is set to 'Automatically'.

If I access the same (or any other application) on a Windows 10 machine with IE11 the caching works.

Any idea why caching is not working in IE11 on Windows 7?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate Question. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835767/ie11-on-windows-7-does-not-cache-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I try to make a test with Windows 7 and IE 11.

I clear the temporary data first and then try to visit several sites in IE 11.

Open the folder which stores temporary data. You can see new files.

If that folder was already opened then **refresh** it.

It will show you a new files.

Try to make a test on your side and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: In Windows 7 IE11 the files are getting stored in Temporary Internet Files folder however the web page in our application takes 50 seconds to load in IE11 - Windows 7 while in IE11 - Windows 10 the same page takes 25 seconds to load. Any idea why the loading is slower in IE11 - Windows 7 compared to Windows 10? Is this the typical behavior of IE11 on Windows 7?

Comment: If we see the original question then it is different then your last comment. In your last comment you had asked a new question. I suggest you to create a new thread if you have a new question. If your original issue is solved then try to mark the helpful answer and close the thread may help other members in future.